# Is it possible to add editable content to the BigCommerce brands page?

Tags: panel, wysiwyg, bigcommerce, banner

We're looking for a way to add a content area to the page listing all brands on the site (https://www.brace-mart.com/brands/) that can be edited with a WYSIWYG editor.  We initially thought of banners, but those can be applied only to specific brands, whereas we want to add content to the listing of all brands.  Is there a method (banner, page, etc.) in BigCommerce to add something like this?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a web page (ex. /all-brands/ ) using a custom template to mimic the current '/brands/' page in your site. In your custom template, you would call in the web page description and brand list HTML. This will allow you to have a WYSIWYG editable content area, and a list of all brands on the same page.

Also remember to add a meta noindex tag to your '/brands/' page you are no longer using to avoid possibly getting penalized for duplicate content as well as change all links referencing this page to your new page.

*Assuming you are using BC Blueprint because you tagged panel.

Comment: Thanks, @tim-diztinct!  I tried this, but there doesn't seem to be any way I can get the image grid from the /brands page to show up using another template.  I'm guessing it checks the URL or hierarchy to decide what to display and simply won't display that on any page other than the /brands page.  Unless you know of a way to get around this?